# Shortest Distance to Point

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 2 vectors, one (vector1 of structs (Point)) is filled with X amount of points and another (vector2 of structs (PrimeTemplate)) is filled with Y amount of points. I want to find all values below a threshold and I feel like my code just doesn't do that. For now I'll just ignore if one point maps to more than 1 other. What am I missing? I only generate a few points and I know I should be getting more.

```
struct Template{
    int tempX;
    int tempY;
};

struct PrimeTemplate{
    double tempX;
    double tempY;
};

int matches = 0;
for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < vector1 .size(); outerLoop++)
    {
        for (int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < vector2.size(); innerLoop++)
        {
            double tempEuclidianX = std::pow(abs(vector1 [outerLoop].tempX - vector2[innerLoop].tempX), 2.0);
            double tempEuclidianY = std::pow(abs(vector1 [outerLoop].tempY - vector2[innerLoop].tempY), 2.0);
            double Euclidian = sqrt(tempEuclidianX + tempEuclidianY);
            if (Euclidian <= 5) //less than threshold
            {
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Sample input from a file would look like this (two different files, random numbers) (no worries about getting data, it's all there)

```
245 21  
452 54  
124 68  
485 78  
111 29  
97  75  
78  113 
300 124 
411 101
```

Comment: You *know* you should be getting more? Based on what? Do you have sample input and expected output that shows your code isn't doing what you want?

Comment: Hi Greg, I have sample output. It's point matching. This is run within 2 for loops as well. so ignore that matches never resets.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you care at all about performance, you want to skip the `sqrt` and compare to the square of the distance, something like `if (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY <= 25) matches++;`.

Comment: performance isn't much of a concern, but another way of looking at it is always welcome! I'll try it out!

Comment: `std::pow` and `abs` are not necessary.  Just take the difference between the points, and multiply them by themselves.  Also, prefer iterators over indices unless you need to know the index of the match (but even that can be done with iterators).

Comment: Perhaps more information will help. Say, the definition of struct Point, your sample input, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the method I used for calculating the shortest distances between a pair. It loops through a text file and loads up the vectors you see. Turned out the issue with the points was in my implementation before this code which was some the normalization of Biometric points.

```
for (int outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < Tvector.size(); outerLoop++)
        {
            for (int innerLoop = 0; innerLoop < QPrimeVector.size(); innerLoop++)
            {
                double tempEuclidianX = std::pow((QPrimeVector[innerLoop].tempX - Tvector[outerLoop].tempX), 2.0);
                double tempEuclidianY = std::pow((QPrimeVector[innerLoop].tempY - Tvector[outerLoop].tempY), 2.0);
                double Euclidian = sqrt(tempEuclidianX + tempEuclidianY);
                if (Euclidian <= THRESHOLD) //less than threshold and not taken already
                {
                    if (Euclidian < minEuclidian)
                    {
                        minEuclidian = Euclidian;
                        if (!Tvector[outerLoop].marked)
                        {
                            matched = innerLoop;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (matched != -1)
                {
                    matches++;
                }
                matched = -1;
                minEuclidian = 10;
            }

            if (matches > masterMatchCount)
            {
                masterMatchCount = matches;
                deltaThetaMaster = deltaTheta;
                deltaXMaster = deltaX;
                deltaYMaster = deltaY;
            }
        }
        for (int reset = 0; reset < Tvector.size(); reset++)
        {
            Tvector[reset].marked = false; //reset all the matches
        }
        QPrimeVector.clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with your code is that you use abs() before squaring.
It isn't necessary to take the absolute value at all before squaring, of course, but if you are going to then you want to use fabs, as just abs takes and returns an integer. This extra rounding off might be why are not getting the right answer.

Comment: It's actually not clear if this is true or not. If [`<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs) is included, there are floating point overloads.  If only [`<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) is included, then we have only the integer overload.

Comment: Hi guys, turns out there was an issue previous to my code when it translated all the points. Lovely negative signs are important now I guess. but  <cmath> was included and I appreciate the input from you guys!

Comment: @snurby77, would you mind posting what you just wrote as an answer and then accepting it? That way, other people visiting this question and experiencing the same problem will be able to jump right to it.

Comment: sorry about that, let me get on it, I forgot about this question